# sed: how to determine if line 1 is contained in line 2

Tags: sed

My text file is sorted alphabetically. I want to determine if each line is contained within the following line, and if so, delete the first of the two. So, for example, if I had...

```
car 
car and trailer
train
```

... I want to end up with...

```
car and trailer
train
```

I found the "sed one-liners" page(s), which has the code to search out duplicate lines:

sed '$!N; /^(.*)\n\1$/!P; D'

... and I figured deleting the ^ would do the trick, but it didn't.

(It would also be nice to do this with non-consecutive lines, but my files run to thousands of lines, and it would probably take a script hours, or days, to run.)

Comment: Ignoring case would be a plus.

Comment: As your RE contain a sign `$` at end, it mean that *line1 match exactly line2* not *line1 is contained in line2*

Comment: As a related suggest, why don't we simply write several python lines to complete this task?

Answer (score 2):

The original command

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

Looks for an exact line match. As you want to check if the first line is contained in the second, you need to add some wild cards:

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n.*\1.*$/!P; D'
```

Should do it.

Comment: No: whith my sample, `echo $'cat\ncat and dog\nhouse\nmoney\ngold and money\n'`, this print `house` too.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks for the edits guys. On my phone so I just copied the cmd from the OP and didn't spot the braces missing. :)

Comment: @F.Hauri house should print as the line following it does not contain house.

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk:

```
awk '$0 !~ prev{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> It would also be nice to do this with non-consecutive lines.

Here is a `bash` script to remove all shorter lines contained within another line, not necessarily consecutive, case-insensitive:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sed with I and Q are gnu extensions:
cat test.txt | while read line; do
   echo Searching for: $line
   sed -n "/.$line/IQ99;/$line./IQ99" test.txt # or grep -i
   if [ $? -eq 99 ]; then
      echo Removing: $line
      sed -i "/^$line$/d" test.txt
   fi   
done
```

Test:

```
$ cat test.txt
Boat
Car
Train and boat
car and cat

$ my_script
Searching for: Boat
Removing: Boat
Searching for: Car
Removing: Car
Searching for: Train and boat
Searching for: car and cat

$ cat test.txt
Train and boat
car and cat
```